# I am taking the text written inside a input field to show in a div, but it is working as a code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

A input field where the user will write what he wants to display

```
<input type="text" class="input-text form-control" placeholder="Input Text">
<div id="paste"></div> //code to be pasted here
```

keyup function called every time user make changes

```
$("#input-text").keyup(function(){
    $("#paste").append(`<div class="form-control">$(".input-text").value</div>`)})
```

When I write "<tagname Hello /tagname>" in input field, it does not get displayed, rather it gets implemented as an HTML code. How can I correct that?

Comment: if you want to get the value using jQuery i would suggest `.val()`, `.value` is a direct reference to the raw html property and doesn't always work correctly with a Jquery selector, also the `.text()` function alters the text content of a html element without the related issues of direct html insertion

Comment: Actually I am applying on multiple classes like `${.input-text}[i].value` in a for loop where `.val()` is not working because of which I'm bound to use `.value`

Comment: if `.val()` is not working it means you have lost the link to the jQuery item, you just need to wrap in `$(var).val()`

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a typo here
`<div id="paste">` //missing one double quote

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple problems with your code, it should be :

```
$("#paste").append('<div class="form-control">' + $(this).val() + '</div>')
```

- It should be `$("#input-text").val()` not `$("#input-text").value` Also you can change `$("#input-text").val()` to `$(this).val()`
- You need to wrap your html `<div class="form-control">$("#input-text").value</div>})` also you have a `}` that should not be there.

**Demo**

```js
$("#input-text").keyup(function() {
  $("#paste").append('<div class="form-control">' + $("#input-text").val() + '</div>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input-text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Text">
<div id="paste"></div> //code to be pasted here
```

Comment: Actually I am applying on multiple classes like ${.input-text}[i].value in a for loop where .val() is not working because of which I'm bound to use .value

Comment: @AyushGupta Your example shows nothing about multiple classes, you use ID and you used a jquery object. If you want examples for multiple class please update your question according.

Comment: I have updated. can you suggest some solution

Answer (score 1):

All the typo-issues aside, your issue is that you are using `.append` with a complete html string.

This will append html.

If you want what you input (eg html tags) to appear as text, then you need to use `.text(newtext)`.  As you're wrapping the input in a div, the easiest way is to generate the div, then add the text.  You could also encode the text when you add it as html, but using `.text(txt)` does this for you.

```
var div = $('<div class="form-control">');
div.text($(this).val())
$("#paste").append(div);
```

You can make this a single line by using `.appendTo()`, which returns the new element rather than .append() which returns the outer element, then chain `.text()`.

```js
$("#input-text").keyup(function() {
  $('<div class="form-control">').appendTo("#paste").text( $(this).val() );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input-text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Text">
<div id="paste"></div> //code to be pasted here
```

Comment: I understood this. But there may be times when I will append a big code ```<div class="col-lg-9 col-12"> 
<div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-text">Q.</div><div class="form-control">${$(".question")[i].value}</div></div></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 offset-lg-1 col-4 offset-8 mt-lg-0 mt-2"><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-text">Marks</div><div class="form-control">${$(".marks")[i].value}</div></div></div>``` and multiple values to it example here only ```${$(".question")[i].value}``` and ```${$(".marks")[i].value}```, then how will I stop

Comment: to read these multiple values to be not read as code but rather as a text